# 403/Forbidden error custom page with Express 3 / Node

Tags: node.js, express

How can I create a route that will handle 403 errors from Express?  I have default routes to catch 404/500 but it seems to stop before ever going to the router. Just stack dumps to screen.

Comment: Can you give examples of what you currently have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To catch errors in express, use middleware that has four arguments:

```
app.use(handleErrors);

function handleErrors(err, req, res, next) {
  res.send('This is your custom error page.');
}
```

To ensure the error is a 403 error, you can do something like:

```
app.use(handle403);

function handle403(err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.status !== 403) return next();
  res.send('403 error');
}
```

Comment: Yes - I also had to make sure it occurred before the  app.use(express.errorHandler()); call. Thanks.